# mysql datetime timezone +0000

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I've got a Twitter database and some columns in multiple tables are time-stamps like:

```
Tue Sep 09 23:48:37 +0000 2014
```

These columns are `TEXT` so I want to convert them. I read
[`Date and Time Types`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), 
[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), and [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). It seems like that there's no symbol to recognize the timezone pattern, and I can't ignore it because it's not at the end of the string therefore `STR_TO_DATE` can't leave it there.

Is there some function or walk-around to deal with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the timezone always `+0000` or does it have different values? You can use constants in the format string http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/21046

Comment: @jkavalik nice shot! In my data it's always `+0000`, I'll give it a try. Thanks!